# Side venting range hood through a chimney

Tags: hvac

After many painful design revisions to update a kitchen built in the 1920s, I think I've finally got it down.  One of my challenges has been being stuck with the location of the stove/oven, because the house chimney is right next to the cooking area. An old stove was once vented into the chimney, back when they used wood, I think.   Currently I have electric, due to the lack of a venting solution, but my design is to have a natural gas cooktop and an electric oven.  Above the cooktop will be the range hood, with a short cabinet above, and a 9" cabinet (to the right) between the hood and the chimney.    My question is: how do I vent the hood so it goes up the chimney, which also serves the boiler?

Comment: What fuel does the boiler use, and is it an atmospheric draft or a forced draft/direct vent appliance? Also, what size is the existing flue liner, or is the chimney being used without one, and what size is the inside of the chimney proper?

Comment: Also, I take it the cooktop is located abutting an interior wall, not an exterior one?